# scratch org with knowledge enabled won't accept custom fields when importing json

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, lightning-knowledge

Given the following scratch org definition file:

```
{
    "orgName": "ScratchMe",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["Knowledge"],
    "hasSampleData": "false",
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "selfSetPasswordInApi": true,
            "s1EncryptedStoragePref2": false                    
        },
        "knowledgeSettings":{
            "enableKnowledge": true,
            "enableLightningKnowledge" : true
        }
    }
}
```

after creating the scratch org and pushing my object field definition files:
[image]

I validate that the Knowledge objects and respective fields exist in the org:
[image]

And when I finally try to import the records from my json file:
`fdx force:data:tree:import --plan ./data/sample-data-plan.json` (i make sure that i target the scratch org with the appropriate username or alias). I get the following Error:

> ERROR:  No such column 'any of my custom fields' on sobject of type
>   Knowledge__kav.

I double-cheked by executing a soql agains the object and its fields, and i get the same error which is odd.

This looks like an issue with the scratch org itself, however, i'm wondering if I may be missing something in my process or configuration. Any thoughts?

I tested a scratch org without knowledge enabled and when through all the configurations manually (enable knowledge user, then knowledge, then lightning knowledge, and finally add the custom fields) and i am able to omport the records accordingly .

eventhough i set the field a object permissions at the profile level for the admin user, they dont seem to be pushed to the org:

```
<fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Knowledge__kav.long_summary__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Knowledge__kav.origin_url__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Knowledge__kav.topic__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
```

Comment: Stupid answer, but - FLS? `data:tree:import` does use the REST API behind the scenes.

Comment: yup - it seems like its that, however, i had set in the admin profile fields and object editable, for some reason they do not appear to be when i look at the profile in the org =/

Comment: When you pushed, did you do a complete source tree push or use one of the new `source:deploy` commands?

Comment: `force:source:push` - i did not use deploy